# Minimum with a correlated subquery mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, greatest-n-per-group

the
Task is:Q: Show For each year, the month with the lowest temperature during the months with more than 150mm of rain.

I did this:

```
SELECT  year,month,tmin  
FROM table_name a
where rain>150 AND tmin= (SELECT MIN(tmin) FROM table_name b  WHERE b.tmin=a.tmin)
```

t.min is the minimum temperature in that month

When I run this, I get for each year the minimum temperature where the rain is >150mm

but there are rows like this:

```
year | month | tmin |
1866 | 1     | 3.8  |
1866 | 2     | 2.9  |
1866 | 11    | 11.1 |
```

and so on..

how do I get here the minimum of those 3 values, so that there is only one data from 1866 and not 3??

Did I do it wrong?

thanks

Comment: This is not a site for solving your homework. Study the theory, investigate and try to pinpoint your problem. Try to formulate your problem in a general way, rather than asking to do your assigned task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated than you think. Not only your correlation clause needs to be fixed (it should match on years), but also you want the `where` condition in the subquery so you can filter on monthes that match the criteria on rain.

Overall, I think that it is easier to `order by` and `limit` in the subquery:

```
select year, month, tmin  
from table_name t
where month = (
    select t1.month
    from table_name t1
    where t1.year = t.year and t1.rain > 150
    order by t1.tmin, t1.month limit 1
)
```

Note: the second ordering criteria is there to break the ties: in this case, the earlierst month of the year having the minimum temperature (and enough rain) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your join is incorrect. You just need to look for min temp for a particular year and then get the month for it. Change the join on `tmin` to `year`

```
select year, 
    month, 
    tmin  
FROM table_name a
where rain > 150 
    AND tmin = (SELECT MIN(tmin) 
                FROM table_name b 
                where a.year=b.year)
```

Comment: the answer from GMB was correct. With this it deleted every year where more than one value. But thank you anyway 